# Outlook 2007: Changing mail account does not change left side menu

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a co-worker who manages the boss's mail account as well as her own. She can read her boss's mail account but when she manages it, it does not change the structure of the left side menu.

Also a shortcut for his mail in her left side menu would be nice to have. :)

Comment: was it added as a mailbox to the original account?

Answer (score 0):

get to `account options` and go to `data files` tab and select the email and hit `settings`
then go to the `advanced` tab and `add` a mailbox. It should show up on her left panel. Any changes she makes will go to the server and change for everyone that uses that mailbox.

Comment: I'll try this the coming Wednesday